# How to add whitespaces for all \cite (s)?

Tags: citing

I'm writing my master thesis and my supervisor suggested me to write always a whitespace before a `\cite{}`, so something like:

> life \cite{perrucci2011survey, satyanarayanan1996fundamental}

And not:

> life\cite{perrucci2011survey, satyanarayanan1996fundamental}

How can I detect (and correct) all the second cases in my document? Bash scripts are an accepted solution.

PS: I'm using TexMaker

Comment: Well, first of all, you should write `\cite{perrucci2011survey,satyanarayanan1996fundamental}`

Comment: @yo' Didn't know this trick, thanks!

Comment: See [how to grep and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402770/how-to-grep-and-replace). I personally use the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15402821/7414040) often.

Comment: Forgot to mention: You can change somedir/  to a path with placeholders. E.g. `*/*.tex` for all .tex files in all subfolders of the working directory.

Comment: With texstudio (a fork of texmaker) you can use the `extended search` and search and replace something for example in all file of a directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since LaTeX ignores two consecutive spaces when compiling, you can just search for `‘\cite{}’` and replace it with `‘ \cite{}’` in your text editor (without the ‘ ’). You will some places get

```
life \cite{perrucci2011survey, satyanarayanan1996fundamental}
```

and some places

```
life  \cite{perrucci2011survey, satyanarayanan1996fundamental}
```

Just ignore the two spaces in your source files, the typesetting will be identical. If the two spaces bother you, you can, as a second step, search for `‘  \cite{}’` (two spaces before) and replace with `‘ \cite{}’` (one space before).

If you do not have an awful lot of files, it should not be much work to open each file and perform the search and replace.